# Pass function result into graphql mutation

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, graphql, react-apollo

My `checker()` function determines if a user's input (checkedNumber) has a match in my database of prime numbers. If there is, I need `updateCheckedNumber()` to run so that `checkedNumber.matchingPrime` is updated with that prime number. I cannot figure out how to pass the prime number to the mutation.

Here's the code form my component. Currently, I'm hardcoding `matchingPrime` to be updated to "100." This reflects correctly in the database.

```
class Prime extends Component {
  updateCheckedNumber = async (checkedNumber) => {
    await this.props.updateCheckedNumber({
      variables: {
        id: checkedNumber.id,
        matchingPrime: checkedNumber.matchingPrime
      },
      update: store => {
        const data = store.readQuery({ query: CheckedNumbersQuery });
        data.checkedNumbers = data.checkedNumbers.map(
          x =>
            x.id === checkedNumber.id
            ? {
                ...checkedNumber, matchingPrime: "100"
              }
            : x
        );
        store.writeQuery({ query: CheckedNumbersQuery, data });
      }
    })
  }

  checker = () => {
    let primes = (this.props.data.primeNumbers)
    let nums = this.props.checkedNumbersFromParent;
    let recentCheckedObject = (nums[nums.length - 1]);
    let recentCheckedNumber = (nums[nums.length - 1].text);
    let recentCheckedRegExp = new RegExp(recentCheckedNumber);
    for (var i in primes) {
      let count = 0;
      if (primes[i].text.search(recentCheckedRegExp) >= 0 && count < 1) {
        count = count + 1;
        this.updateCheckedNumber(recentCheckedObject);
      }
    }
  }
```

Here are my resolvers from my server side:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    primeNumbers: () => PrimeNumber.find(),
    checkedNumbers: () => CheckedNumber.find()
  },
  Mutation: {
    createCheckedNumber: async (_, {text}) => {
      const checkedNumber = new CheckedNumber({text, matchingPrime: "nada"});
      await checkedNumber.save();
      return checkedNumber;
    },
    updateCheckedNumber: async (_, {id, matchingPrime}) => {
      await CheckedNumber.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {matchingPrime});
      return true;
    },
```

Thank you very much for looking at this.

Comment: Are you using `react-apollo`?

Comment: Yes, I am using react-apollo

Comment: I'm going to post an *answer* because of the required room. It might not solve it one shot.

Comment: Understood. Thank you very much, Kyle.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have a resolver, but I haven't seen a schema for your `updateCheckedNumber` resolver. Given your resolver we can make a schema as follows:

```
##updateCheckedNumber.graphql
type Prime {
  id: String
  value: Number
}

type Mutation {
  updateCheckedNumber(id: String!, matchingPrime: Number!): Prime
}
```

Now you're going to need a query string that you can pass into your react component as a prop. We can do that using `gql` from `graphql-tag` as follows:

```
const updateCheckedNumber = gql`
  mutation updateCheckedNumber($id: String!, $matchingPrime: Number!) {
    updateCheckedNumber(id: $id, matchingPrime: $matchingPrime) {
      id,
      value
    }
  }
`
```

Now that we have that we need to wrap our react component with `graphql` from `react-apollo` as follows:

```
export default graphql(updateCheckedNumber, {
  name: 'updateCheckedNumber'
})(MyReactComponent)
```

Now inside your react component you have access to `props.updateCheckedNumber` and you call it like this:

```
props.updateCheckedNumber({
  variables: {
    id: theId,
    matchingPrime: theCheckedNumber
  }
})
```

Hope this helps!

P.S. If you have a Query that that gives you a list of the prime numbers, such as `primeNumbers`, you will need to refetchQueries in the options of the `graphql` call. Or update your `InMemoryCache` manually.

Comment: Thank you @KyleRichardson. I'm still not sure how I pass in the matching prime number to `updateCheckedNumber`. The `checker()` function tells me if a prime number can be found that matches `recentCheckedNumber`. But how do I take that prime number and add it to `checkedNumber.matchingPrime`? I get an undefined error when I simply pass `primeNumber` to `updateCheckedNumber()`. Thank you again for your help